# ¿Cómo pasar los datos de un JTable a una matriz bidimensional?

Tags: java, array, jtable

Mi problema es el siguiente;

quisiera saber si estoy usando el método `getValueAt` de manera correcta, estoy recorriendo un `jtable` llamado `tblMatriz`, y trato de almacenar los valores en una matriz bidimensional , el siguiente código lo utilizo para guardar:

```
public double[][] guardar() {

    double[][] array_reg = new double[tblMatriz.getRowCount()][tblMatriz.getColumnCount()];        

    int fila1 = tblMatriz.getRowCount();
    int col1 = tblMatriz.getColumnCount();   
    int i,j;       

    for (i = 0; i < fila1; i++) {            

        for (j = 0; j <  col1 ;j++) {                   

           array_reg[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, 0));         
        }
    }

    return array_reg;
}
```

Y al momento de ejecutar el programa, relleno una matriz 2*2 yo determino el tamaño),

A | B

---

1 | 2

---

3 | 4 
y el resultado que me da en consola es; 
1
1.

Cabe mencionar que para imprimir la matriz, le doy clic a un botón llamado Calcular.

```
 private void jbtnCalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int fila = 0, columna = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    try {

        fila = Integer.parseInt(txtFilas.getText());
        columna = Integer.parseInt(txtColumnas.getText());

        double matrix[][] = new double[fila][columna];

        matrix = this.guardar();


        for (i = 0; i <= fila; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= columna; j++) {

                System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // this.mostrarMatrizInversa();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Perfect");

    }
```

Comment: En teoría creo que tu código esta bien, pero si debes cambiar el `0` por la variable `j`; Pero creo que te falta obtener el modelo de tu tabla, para obtener los datos de la fila.

Comment: `DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable tabla = new JTable (modelo);` desconozco tu código pero en teoría tendrías que tener algo similar.

Answer (score 0):

Estas recogiendo siempre la primera columna con este código

```
array_reg[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, 0));
```

Cambia el 0 por j para obtener el valor bueno

```
array_reg[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j));
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado, pero no me almacena los valores en la matriz 2*2, porque después de de rellenar las celdas, le doy la instrucción de mostrar los valores de la matriz con dos for como explique en el codigo anterior, y no me sale nada en consola. Y tampoco me sale error.

La única manera en la que me imprime todos los valores de una  sola fila de la tabla es con el siguiente código :

`
  array_reg[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, 0));

            array_reg[i][j]=Double.parseDouble((String) tblMatriz.getValueAt(0, j));`